# ':app:processDebugResources'. error in Android Studio 3.1

Tags: android-studio

I don't know what exactly causes this error but i've searched everywhere and nothing can solve it, it getting worst! When i build my app it shows  **AAPT2 error: check logs for details**. See the screenshots.[image] [image]

My project build.gradle file

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
       // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha13'

        // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha11'
      // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And my app build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
       // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha13'

        // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha11'
      // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I am in the middle of my thesis and it causes me a big big problem. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your gradle.properties file

`android.enableAapt2=true`

Comment: please set android.enableAapt2=false instead of android.enableAapt2=true.

Comment: `WARNING: The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.`

Comment: Welcome Debbie !! :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at what the errors are - in the second picture you attached there are 3 Android issues (the three last issues in the window on the left side). They are saying that there's a problem with some 3 attributes. If you click onto them you will be able to see the whole error and then fix the issue.

Comment: `error: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimary (aka com.example.owner.foodal11_2:attr/colorPrimary)' not found.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimary (aka com.example.owner.foodal11_2:attr/colorPrimary)' not found., sources=[C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-26.1.0.aar\2743de8bfcf56b2faf350423b91d3d0a\res\values\values.xml:49:5-117], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}`   

It tried to remove android tag from values.xml because it was in red color like error, but when i rebuild the same error appears.

Comment: i change compile and targetSdk to 27 and support:appcompat to 27.0.1 but now i have this error
`Program type already present: org.jsoup.Connection$Request
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: org.jsoup.Connection$Request, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}`

Answer (score 0):

To trace error
try running the following command in your project directory

> gradlew assembleDebug